# Webform-CiviCRM and the "my billing address is the same" checkbox

Tags: civicontribute, drupal, webform-civicrm

On a core contribution page, if you add an address profile at the top of the page, a checkbox appears allowing the user to indicate that their billing address is the same:
[image: My billing address is the same as above]

On a Webform-CiviCRM form, my understanding is that the payment page is always a separate page and this box is not automatic. Is there any way to include a checkbox like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature has not been implemented in Webform-CiviCRM. If you do see that box in a webform, it's a mistake (and the fix is to remove profiles from the contribution page you are using for the webform).

Implementation of this feature would require writing some javascript to fill those fields from available data, and some php code to store the data across potentially multiple pages. The best place to put it might be in `wf_crm_webform_preprocess::addResources`.

Note that if the user is logged-in then the billing fields will already be pre-filled.

Comment: and if we use a checksum but neither Billing Name fields nor address fields prefill? can you point me in a direction for head scratching? would you expect this to prefill? using Authorize.net

Comment: @coleman: We have few requirements coming through to be able to use this checkbox for anonymous users.
Is this something the module developers can implement? Thanks.

Comment: @coleman whats the status of this one - is it still not in webform CiviCRM? Your last comment is a few years old. thanks