# How to include "Same as Billing/Home address" in a payment processing page?

Tags: profile, payment-processor, contribution-page

I know This can be easily done by webform. But Civicrm webform does not allow the price set to be included. So its a limitation...

We use paypal website pro service. A profile is included to the payment page to include donors home address. Is there a way to include a check box to state "Same as Billing/Home address" in the profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe [the checkbox should appear automatically](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/604/webform-civicrm-and-the-my-billing-address-is-the-same-checkbox) on a core Contribution page as long as the profile with the home address is at the top of the page, not the bottom.

[image: Profiles]

Comment: Thanks, I have added the home address to bottom of page and thats why it was not working. but now it does after adding it in top of the page!!

Comment: I knew that was true but couldn't figure out why it wasn't showing up. So this is basically undocumented.

Comment: @herb I just submitted a PR to the user guide: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide/pull/115