# Webform - autofilled fields using "Existing User"

Tags: webform-civicrm

I often use the "existing user" field in a Webform so that authenticated users don't have to re-enter info that we already have in CiviCRM.

This works well but I realized that collection fields that exist after a page break, meaning not in the same page as the "existing user" field, aren't populated and remain blank.

Am I missing something? Is there a way around this?

Comment: Sounds similar to this issue perhaps https://www.drupal.org/node/2316565

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into something very similar previously - and here's how I solved it:

[How can I (on page 2) show First Name of an Existing Contact - static (on page 1) without dragging it to page 2?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4621/how-can-i-on-page-2-show-first-name-of-an-existing-contact-static-on-page-1)